# A question on homeomorphism definition

Tags: real-analysis

The definition of homeomorphism states the map must be continuous and bijective **and as well as its inverse**.

What I don't understand is, why do they state the inverse needs also to be continuous? I thought by being one-to-one and continuous on an interval already gives us a continuous inverse for free?

Comment: "being one-to-one and continuous **on an interval** already gives us a continuous inverse" That is particular to intervals (where the range is also an interval). Homeomorphism is a more general concept, and for other domains/ranges, the inverse of a continuous bijective function need not be continuous.

Comment: The notion is not exclusive about maps from intervals to intervals. It can be applied in much more general situations. You are right that injective continuous maps from an interval to $\mathbb R$ are automatically homeomorphisms with their image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the map $$T(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$$ from the interval $[0,2\pi)$ to the unit circle. It is bijective and continuous, but it is **not** continuously invertible because points far apart (near $0$ and near $2\pi$) map to points close together (the point $(1,0)$ on the unit circle).

Topologically, it would be wrong to say that an interval is homeomorphic to the unit circle. They are different, and a discontinuous inverse is a symptom of this.

---

EDIT

First, what you wrote in the comments is not the inverse. The inverse would be $$T^{-1}\big(\cos x,\sin x\big)=x$$ Remember that $T:[0,2\pi)\subset\mathbb{R}\to\text{Unit Circle}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ maps from one-dimensional to two-dimensional space.

For a map to be continuous, points close together have to go to points close together. In this case, points very near $(1,0)$ but *counterclockwise* from it map to numbers very near $0$. On the other hand, points very near $(1,0)$ but *clockwise* from it map to numbers very near $2\pi$. So even though, for example, the points $(\cos 0.01,\sin 0.01)$ and $(\cos -0.01,\sin -0.01)$ are extremely close in $\mathbb{R}^2$, they map far away. There is a sort of "jump discontinuity" at that point.

This problem results because a circle comes back to where it started but the line segment does not. This, essentially, is the difference between the two topological spaces. If you take the two endpoints of the line segment and 'glue' them together (using the identification topology) you will find that the result is homeomorphic to a circle. In fact, the very function we have been considering induces such a homeomorphism, because the identification operates on the equality $T(0)=T(2\pi)=(1,0)$.

Comment: WOuld you be able to elaborate more on that example? The inverse is $T^{-1} = (arccos, arcsin)$ Also, even though it maps points close together, it is not the same; so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @sidht See edit.